# Angular POST request securing

Tags: angular, security, post, angular-httpclient

I am new to angular and I have below question kindly help. If I make POST request from my Angular Code to the third-party API how I can ensure that my POST request data will not be hacked and manipulation by others.

Comment: Please see : https://angular.io/guide/security

Answer (score 0):

Mostly `http://` post requests are more vulnerable to hack data which you are sending in the post request. to make it secure you need send data over `https://`

In angular, you can intercept the HTTP request with the following code and make it secure.

```
// clone request and replace 'http://' with 'https://' at the same time
const secureReq = req.clone({
  url: req.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
});
// send the cloned, "secure" request to the next handler.
return next.handle(secureReq);
```

[Here is official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Hope this will help!